# How to start new lists with 1 in a custom style?

Tags: ms-word, docx

I use a docx template to create documents programmatically from HTML. I have a custom style s_numberic for numbered lists. When I open the template in MS Word, all lists created with this style continue numbering from the previous, even though there are texts between them.

[image]

How can I avoid it?

This is styles properties.

s_numreric:

```
Indent:
    Left:  0"
    Hanging:  0.25", Suppress line numbers, Outline numbered + Level: 1 + Numbering Style: 1, 2, 3, … + Start at: 1 + Alignment: Left + Aligned at:  -0.39" + Indent at:  -0.14", Style: Linked, Show in the Styles gallery
    Based on: s_dots
```

s_dots:

```
Indent:
    Left:  0"
    Hanging:  0.2", Space
    After:  2 pt, Bulleted + Level: 1 + Aligned at:  1.43" + Indent at:  1.68", Style: Linked, Show in the Styles gallery
    Based on: s_text
```

s_text:

```
Justified
    Line spacing:  single, Space
    After:  3 pt, Style: Linked, Show in the Styles gallery
    Based on: Normal
```